# How can I chain CanActivate in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template

I have the following route definition...

```
const COMMON_ROUTES = [
    {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginComponent,
        pathMatch: "prefix",
        canActivate: [ CanActivateIfAnonymous ],
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                component: PasswordLoginComponent,
                canActivate: [CanActivateIfPassword],
            },
            {
                path: "pki",
                component: PkiLoginComponent,
                canActivate: [CanActivateIfPki],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

Then I have my CanActivates...

```
export class CanActivateIfPassword implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loginSettingsService: LoginSettingService,
                private router: Router) { }
    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot,
    ) {
        console.log("Password Check");
        return this.loginSettingsService.loginSettings.map(settings =>{
            console.log("Password Check Finished");
            return true;
        });
    }
}
export class CanActivateIfPki implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loginSettingsService: LoginSettingService) { }
    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot,
    ) {
        console.log("PKI Check");
        return this.loginSettingsService.loginSettings.map((settings) => {
            console.log("PKI Check Finished");
            return settings["pki"];
        });
    }
}
```

But when I run this I would expect...

```
Password Check
Password Check Finished
PKI Check
PKI Check Finished
```

But instead I get...

```
Password Check
PKI Check
PKI Check Finished
```

I do notice that loginSettings is a value and not an observable so the other observable comes first. I will try to post a plunker soon.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yK0eGoUGIVvKZu45jSBs?p=preview)

This one prints out like...

```
Password Check
PKI Check
PKI Check Finished
Password Check Finished
```

Which is also not what I want. So I will check on the missing statement but my question still applies. But it actually makes sense because in my code PKI is redirecting.

Comment: Hmm, strange indeed. On a side note: why do you have `router` variable in your first constructor? And is there a chance that your return value in Password class is undefined? Can you maybe show us your loginService?

Comment: Ok I updated to show what I want vs what I expect...

Comment: Check comments [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11161)

Comment: That thread says closed, but yeah it still fails. I left a comment but :-(